# CPT permalinks Rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

Someone please can help me to change my Cpt permalink.
i'm using JEtengine cpt, does the permalink structure can be changed

from `www.example.com/request/post_title` to `www.example.com/request/post_id` ?

in permalink wp settings, changing settings does not affect JetEngine CustomPostType...

someone have snippet or code for `functions.php` to improve this changes?

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any experience with JetEngine CPT, but you can try:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpse404402_post_type_link', 10, 2);

function wpse404402_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    return home_url( 'cpt-type/' . $post->ID );
}
```

Don't forget to flush permalinks after that.

Also - maybe JetEngine CPT also uses this filter, try to see maybe changing the priority on that add_filter would help. You can also search in the code of the plugin if it uses this filter.